# importing module in python giving two different output in interpreter and script file

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, ssl

I can't understand why the two methods of running python code would have different results when loading a module.

The script file I am executing is called `ssl.py`

```
import httplib
import sys

print sys.version_info
print dir(httplib)
```

This is the command window output I am receiving

```
C:\tests>python ssl.py
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
['ACCEPTED', 'BAD_GATEWAY', 'BAD_REQUEST', 'CONFLICT', 'CONTINUE', 'CREATED', 'E
XPECTATION_FAILED', 'FAILED_DEPENDENCY', 'FORBIDDEN', 'FOUND', 'GATEWAY_TIMEOUT'
, 'GONE', 'HTTP', 'HTTPConnection', 'HTTPMessage', 'HTTPResponse', 'HTTPS_PORT',
 'HTTP_PORT', 'HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED', 'IM_USED', 'INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE', '
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'LENGTH_REQUIRED', 'LOCKED', 'MAXAMOUNT', 'METHOD_NOT_AL
LOWED', 'MOVED_PERMANENTLY', 'MULTIPLE_CHOICES', 'MULTI_STATUS', 'NON_AUTHORITAT
IVE_INFORMATION', 'NOT_ACCEPTABLE', 'NOT_EXTENDED', 'NOT_FOUND', 'NOT_IMPLEMENTE
D', 'NOT_MODIFIED', 'NO_CONTENT', 'OK', 'PARTIAL_CONTENT', 'PAYMENT_REQUIRED', '
PRECONDITION_FAILED', 'PROCESSING', 'PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED', 'REQUESTED_
RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE', 'REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE', 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT', 'REQUEST_
URI_TOO_LONG', 'RESET_CONTENT', 'SEE_OTHER', 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE', 'SWITCHING_P
ROTOCOLS', 'StringIO', 'TEMPORARY_REDIRECT', 'UNAUTHORIZED', 'UNPROCESSABLE_ENTI
TY', 'UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE', 'UPGRADE_REQUIRED', 'USE_PROXY', '_CS_IDLE', '_CS
_REQ_SENT', '_CS_REQ_STARTED', '_MAXHEADERS', '_MAXLINE', '_UNKNOWN', '__all__',
 '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'array', 'mim
etools', 'os', 'py3kwarning', 'responses', 'socket', 'urlsplit', 'warnings']

C:\tests>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib
>>> dir(httplib)
['ACCEPTED', 'BAD_GATEWAY', 'BAD_REQUEST', 'BadStatusLine', 'CONFLICT', 'CONTINU
E', 'CREATED', 'CannotSendHeader', 'CannotSendRequest', 'EXPECTATION_FAILED', 'F
AILED_DEPENDENCY', 'FORBIDDEN', 'FOUND', 'FakeSocket', 'GATEWAY_TIMEOUT', 'GONE'
, 'HTTP', 'HTTPConnection', 'HTTPException', 'HTTPMessage', 'HTTPResponse', 'HTT
PS', 'HTTPSConnection', 'HTTPS_PORT', 'HTTP_PORT', 'HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED',
 'IM_USED', 'INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE', 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'ImproperConnection
State', 'IncompleteRead', 'InvalidURL', 'LENGTH_REQUIRED', 'LOCKED', 'LineAndFil
eWrapper', 'LineTooLong', 'MAXAMOUNT', 'METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED', 'MOVED_PERMANENTLY'
, 'MULTIPLE_CHOICES', 'MULTI_STATUS', 'NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION', 'NOT_ACCE
PTABLE', 'NOT_EXTENDED', 'NOT_FOUND', 'NOT_IMPLEMENTED', 'NOT_MODIFIED', 'NO_CON
TENT', 'NotConnected', 'OK', 'PARTIAL_CONTENT', 'PAYMENT_REQUIRED', 'PRECONDITIO
N_FAILED', 'PROCESSING', 'PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED', 'REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_S
ATISFIABLE', 'REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE', 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT', 'REQUEST_URI_TOO_LON
G', 'RESET_CONTENT', 'ResponseNotReady', 'SEE_OTHER', 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE', 'SW
ITCHING_PROTOCOLS', 'StringIO', 'TEMPORARY_REDIRECT', 'UNAUTHORIZED', 'UNPROCESS
ABLE_ENTITY', 'UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE', 'UPGRADE_REQUIRED', 'USE_PROXY', 'Unimpl
ementedFileMode', 'UnknownProtocol', 'UnknownTransferEncoding', '_CS_IDLE', '_CS
_REQ_SENT', '_CS_REQ_STARTED', '_MAXHEADERS', '_MAXLINE', '_UNKNOWN', '__all__',
 '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'array', 'err
or', 'mimetools', 'os', 'py3kwarning', 'responses', 'socket', 'ssl', 'urlsplit',
 'warnings']
>>>
```

You will notice that the HTTPSConnection method is in one version of httplib and not the other. Why is this happening?

Comment: You can do `print httplib` after having imported it to display the path of the library you are currently using.

Comment: Both appear to be using `<module 'httplib' from 'C:\Python27\lib\httplib.pyc'>` HTTPSConnection appears in that file too. Yet I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'` when trying to use it.

Comment: according to `httplib` source code, it tries to import module `ssl` and only if succeeded it adds `HTTPSConnection` to `__all__`.  Can you try to import `ssl` from your script?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_create_default_https_context'` - Look like the ssl module isn't installed?

Comment: @DannyCullen it should be there. Moreover, in `Python 2.7.9` release `ssl` was backported from `Python 3.4`

Comment: @DannyCullen have you tried another name for **your** script? Rename it to `s.py` and run it again.

Comment: Problem solved guys. My script was called `ssl.py` I think it was getting confused with the module name.

Answer (score -1):

Once I changed my script name from `ssl.py` to `anotherName.py` all is fine. IT was getting confused when I was trying to import the module ssl

Comment: it would be great to include explanations why you were getting the problem or ask werewindle to post an answer